# Winforms expander implementation

Tags: c#, expander

I have got the expander from https://jfblier.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/rich-panel-with-expander/

I have added it to my project but have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Your statement is not even a question... Are you not failiar to 3rd party dlls, or dont you know how the designer works?

Comment: Sorry. I have added the dll to my project as a reference, but tgats as far as i have managed to get...bit of a noob when it comes to adding things. I am trying to get an expandable box into the project so that i can put a couple of controls in it (radiobuttons) but i am not sure how to get a "box" on the screen. To begin playing with. Thought there might have been a "create expander" option or something but i cant find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your 3rd party-dll as reference to your solution, right click Toolbox and select *choose item*. After this a window appears, letting you select a massive amount of dll's. Hit the *Browse*-Button and select the dll containing your Expander. The list of dll's should now have updated.

Now find and check your desired control and confirm the dialog.

Your expander should now be availiable in the Toolbox. Simply drag/drop it on your Form/Usercontrol and you're done

Comment: Ahhhh, of course. Forgot about the toolbox step. Will try when i get home. Thanks